# SUM of a LEFT OUTER JOIN of a GROUPED BY Column Giving Aggregated Value instead of singular expected instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have searched quite extensively for a previous question similar to the one I'm about to ask, but can only find advice on GROUP BY clauses.

I've hit a SQL computation that I do not understand - which is due to my current understanding of GROUPING and AGGREGATE functions in MSSQL (2008 R2).

The SQL statement at the base of this post - I have grouped by Email address - and due to Grouping Rules (line 2 - i.e. NewC.ToAddress not defined in my GroupBy) - I have used a Aggregate Function for the column SQL.

The result I expect (and want) is 2.  If I use MAX I get 2.

However, with my current understanding, I would expect SUM to also return a result of 2.  But for some reason that I do not yet understand it returns 6.

I would be most grateful if anyone can help correct my misguided understanding.

See Below: -

```
DECLARE @TA TABLE(EMAIL VARCHAR(25))
DECLARE @TB TABLE(EMAIL VARCHAR(25), ID INT)
DECLARE @TC TABLE(EMAIL VARCHAR(25), ToAddress INT)

INSERT INTO @TA VALUES ('A@B.C')
INSERT INTO @TB VALUES ('A@B.C', 0),('A@B.C', 1),('A@B.C', 2)
INSERT INTO @TC VALUES ('A@B.C', 2)

SELECT
    ISNULL(SUM(NewC.ToAddress), 0) AS NewCustomersContactedCount
FROM @TA MasterTable
    INNER JOIN @TB SentMails ON SentMails.EMAIL = MasterTable.EMAIL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @TC NewC ON NewC.EMAIL = MasterTable.EMAIL
GROUP BY 
    MasterTable.EMAIL
```

Comment: Your `JOIN` is produces multiple rows, because multiple rows match emails.

Comment: Try COUNT(DISTINCT NewC.ToAddress) not SUM().  SUM is used to add up numeric expressions, not strings.

Comment: To better understand the query you should try it without grouping by and just `select *`

Comment: In my opinion, you should also move the `ISNULL`. This won't solve your problem, but it could solve a future problem. Change your `SELECT ISNULL(SUM(NewC.ToAddress), 0)` to `SELECT SUM(ISNULL(NewC.ToAddress,0))`

Comment: RE:Gordon Linoff.  I understand the multiple row matches, however I had thought that the GROUP BY would have aggregated the MasterTable.EMAIL prior to applying the SUM function.  From EionS's sample I am seeing that the SUM function most likely works off a return result set before any GROUPING is applied

Comment: RE: vercelli.  It's not the understanding of the query that has caused my anguish, but rather the sequence of events that has gone against my current understanding - which is under change.  I currently can't find specific documentation to clarify the actual sequence of event for this circumstance, which would be first prize.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check your join, when you select this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM @TA MasterTable
    INNER JOIN @TB SentMails ON SentMails.EMAIL = MasterTable.EMAIL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @TC NewC ON NewC.EMAIL = MasterTable.EMAIL
```

It returns this:

```
    EMAIL   EMAIL   ID  EMAIL   ToAddress
1   A@B.C   A@B.C   0   A@B.C   2
2   A@B.C   A@B.C   1   A@B.C   2
3   A@B.C   A@B.C   2   A@B.C   2
```

When you group this by MasterTable.email, the sum of toAddress for that email is indeed 6.

Comment: Thanks EoinS, so would agree that it would be safe assumption that Aggregate functions work on the result set that is returned before the GROUP BY function.  Reason I ask is that I am still looking for documentation to corroborate this assumption, as well as provide interesting reading in regards to MSSQL execution plan.

Comment: Correct.  If you are an excel user this would be similar to a sumif on each unique email from the table above

Comment: EionS: Hmm - I dislike Excel - never used the sumif function, so don't know how it works, I much prefer SQL doing the hard work, and excel to prettify the deliverable.  I've sort of figured out what threw me into a spin.  If we added another MasterEmail (D@E.F) and 3 B entries and 1 corresponding C (with a value of say 4) entry - reapplied the group by - the origional query I posted would give a result of 6 and 12.  Which implies that GROUP BY has a pre-algorithmic execution plan before applying the aggregate function - but, and this is what I've had to digest, only on the columns defined in

Comment: \after the GROUP BY clause.  Therefore the aggregates execute against a parallel set of results.  I am still looking for decent documentation on this though.  I would imagine sumif wouldn't handle GROUP BY functionality - havn't checked, just guessing.